# android - set image in background of part of a text in text view

Tags: android, textview, background-image

I want to implement a book in android with some option. one of these is to set a picture in background of **part of text** . how can I do this??

thanks

Comment: use a compound textview.

Comment: android:background="@drawable/image"

Answer (score 2):

Use below code in your XML file.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/yourImageName"
    />
```

Comment: I do not mean this. I have to set image to part of text . for example two last character

Answer (score 0):

Set textview background

```
android:background="@drawable/imgsrc"
```

Comment: I want to set image part of text view not all of it

Answer (score 0):

try this and fix heght of imageview ase per you requirement

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```